# Xamarin iOS Object Disposed Exception in Insights after update

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mono

I'm having a weird problem since I updated to the latest version of Xamarin. My App is behaving normally but in Xamarin Insights I get reports of a crash.

I'm getting a System.ObjectDisposedException at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.

The complete stack trace that Insights shows me is only 3 lines long, which is not very helpful. And although Insights reports a crash, the app itself is not crashing at all.

I searched the internet and StackOverflow but I didn't find a solution so far. Maybe anyone in here has experienced some similar issues or knows how to fix this.

Im currently using:

Visual Studio for Mac: 7.3 (build 797)

Mono: 5.4.1.7

Xamarin.iOS : 11.4.0.214

The link below shows the complete StackTrace from Xamarin Insights.

[Complete Stacktrace from Xamarin Insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKrQd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly related to a Xamarin Bugzilla bug here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=61002

That was also reported early December, and one user suggested dropping to Xamarin.iOS 11.2 and XCode 9, though that's not something we can do here. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed by Xamarin in the current service release.

https://releases.xamarin.com/service-release-15-5-5/